# XSLT 2.0 previous value in a for-each-group

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given this kind of structure:

```
<ROOT>
    <MYROW>
        <CATEGORYNAME>first</CATEGORYNAME>
        <DATA>10</DATA>
    </MYROW>
    <MYROW>
        <CATEGORYNAME>second</CATEGORYNAME>
        <DATA>20</DATA>
    </MYROW>
    <MYROW>
        <CATEGORYNAME>second</CATEGORYNAME>
        <DATA>30</DATA>
    </MYROW>
    <MYROW>
        <CATEGORYNAME>first</CATEGORYNAME>
        <DATA>100</DATA>
    </MYROW>
</ROOT>
```

I am doing this kind of transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <Worksheet>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="MYROW" group-by="CATEGORYNAME">
                <ROW>
                    <CELL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </CELL>
                </ROW>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Worksheet>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MYROW">
        <ROW>
            <CELL>
                <xsl:value-of select="DATA"/>
            </CELL>
        </ROW>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I would like to compare the "DATA" value with its previous one in the group. I can't manage to get the previous value. I tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::node()/DATA"/>
```

which gives all the previous sibling nodes in the original XML and not just in the current group by.

Basically I want to know if there is a way to use xpath within a group-by sequence.

Expected output:

```
<Worksheet>
   <ROW>
      <CELL>
         <DATA>first</DATA>
      </CELL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <CELL>
         <DATA color = "black">10</DATA>
      </CELL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <CELL>
         <DATA color = "blue">100</DATA>
      </CELL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <CELL>
         <DATA color = "red">5</DATA>
      </CELL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <CELL>
         <DATA>second</DATA>
      </CELL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <CELL>
         <DATA color = "black">20</DATA>
      </CELL>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <CELL>
         <DATA color = "blue">30</DATA>
      </CELL>
   </ROW>
</Worksheet>
```

Comment: Can you post the result you want to achieve? It is not clear whether you want to compare a `DATA` element to its preceding `DATA` in the original input XML or to a preceding group member. And it is not clear what you want to compare, perhaps you want a nested grouping by `DATA`?

Comment: for example, for my first group named "first" I have the value 10 and 100 successively. I want to know if 100 is greater than its previous value 10 or not. to give you more context, my DATA value are in chronological order, this is why I want to make the comparaison, but within each group.

Comment: so I want to compare to the predecing group member.

Comment: You might need to store the grouping result in a variable then and process that variable further to access a preceding group member. Or perhaps you only want to sort the group, you still haven't said or shown which result you want.

Comment: I want to set an attribute to the data element in the output. Let's say this attribute is color and its value is black is element is first or equal to the preceding, red if value is below and blue if value is higher. This is for XML to excel output and it will help me to put color in the excel. Example of output above.

Comment: But if you group first by `CATEGORYNAME` as shown in your XSLT sample then you don't get the result you have now added at all, the result is different, it is the one from your earlier posting and the suggested solution http://xsltransform.net/pPzifp8. Why is there now a `<CATEGORYNAME>first</CATEGORYNAME>` at the end, although you group?

Comment: sorry I rectify my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>` as shown and then a template for the `<xsl:template match="MYROW">` then you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <Worksheet>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="MYROW" group-by="CATEGORYNAME">
                <ROW>
                    <CELL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </CELL>
                </ROW>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Worksheet>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MYROW">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>                                                                      
        <xsl:variable name="preceding-group-member" select="current-group()[$pos - 1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="this-data" select="xs:decimal(DATA)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="preceding-data" select="xs:decimal($preceding-group-member/DATA)"/>
        <ROW>
            <CELL color="{if ($pos eq 1 or $this-data eq $preceding-data) 
                         then 'black' else (if ($this-data gt $preceding-data) then 'blue' else 'red')}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="DATA"/>
            </CELL>
        </ROW>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/pPzifp8/1.